# Load ResourceDictionary component in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Im pretty new to coding and struggling with this for the last few hours and can't even find the proper way to do it.

I want to load all the data from one `ResourceDictionary` Skin.xaml in `DataGrid` and display it on screen so the user can then change the content and save it back to the same skin or another one.

this is part of the data from the `ResourceDictionary` xaml

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button01" Color="#FFABABAB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TitleBar" Color="#FFABABAB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="#FF5B5B5B"/>
```

I alredy created the `DataGrid` and binded a `DataTable` to it to insert the data

```
this.ResourceToLoad = new DataTable("Resources");
        DataColumn workCol = ResourceToLoad.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
        workCol.Unique = true;
        this.ResourceToLoad.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(String));
        dgResources.DataContext = this;
```

The problem I have is how to insert the data from the `ResourceDictionary` to the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ResourceDictionary` is loaded in your context you can do the following to load a resource:

```
var buttonBrush = (Brush)FindResource("Button01");
```

Otherwise you have to first load the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
ResourceDictionary loadedDictionary;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("yourpath/Skin.xaml", FileMode.Open))
    {
       loadedDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
    }

var buttonBrush = (Brush)loadedDictionary["Button01"];
```

**Edit:**
With a foreach loop you could get key and value of the dictionary entry:

```
 foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in loadedDictionary)
 {
    var key = entry.Key;
    var resource = entry.Value;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot ... now I see what I was missing :)

Comment: posted below for more space

Comment: thnx alot for the help again, you are a lifesaver :)